# Vectorization of custom numeric type in c#

Tags: c#, vector, .net-core, vectorization, simd

I am wondering if it is possible to optimize division of 2 arrays of custom numeric types.

I have 2 arrays of `Int24` that i need to divide fast.

Should i cast them to `Int32` and use `Vector<Int32>`, or pack them so i can give more data to the registers, or can i use some SIMD instinct directly (PPE, SPEs)?

```cs
    [Serializable]
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 3)]
    [DebuggerDisplay("{Value}")]
    public readonly partial struct Int24
        : IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible, IComparable<Int24>, IComparable<int>, IEquatable<Int24>, IEquatable<int>
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        private readonly byte _byte1;

        [FieldOffset(1)]
        private readonly byte _byte2;

        [FieldOffset(2)]
        private readonly byte _byte3;
```